# PHP Fulltext search is not working as expected

Tags: php, mysql, full-text-search, full-text-indexing

I am querying data for feltering my database column based on the keyword user types in.

Suppose if user want to search zip code and types `114` so our script should come up with results having zip from database zip field in them mean pattern matching or what I am not sure, next if user want to query address and types desired address so our system should comes up with address from database address field.

The code I am using is:

```
$test       =   $_REQUEST['keyword'];

echo $query_rsTest = "SELECT zip, ste, st, st_num, town, addr, st_sfx,
MATCH (zip, ste, st, st_num, town, addr, st_sfx) against('*$test*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) as relevance
FROM
tbl_property
WHERE MATCH (zip, ste, st, st_num, town, addr, st_sfx) against('*$test*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) order by relevance desc limit 0,5";

$rsTest = mysql_query($query_rsTest) or die(mysql_error());
$row_rsTest = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsTest);

if  (isset($row_rsTest['zip'])) {?>
    <div id='fetchRecs'><ul>
    <?php
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rsTest)) {
        echo '<li><a href="#">'.$row['zip'].'</a></li>';
    }
    ?>
    </ul></div>
<?php } elseif (isset($row_rsTest['ste'])){?>
    <div id='fetchRecs'><ul>
    <?php
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rsTest)) {
        echo '<li><a href="#">'.$row['ste'].'</a></li>';
    }
    ?>
    </ul></div>
<?php }
```

Here is my table structure and the sample records.

[image]

I simply want user to get exact result based on his query from the database. Means if we can filter database columns, like user type some blah blah keyword so we should matched it and query appropriate column for results from blah blah column only.

Thanks.

Comment: `against('$test' IN BOOLEAN MODE)`

Comment: No lucks please..Can you post the query please?

Answer (score 0):

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE tbl_property;`

Looking for `114` as the prefix to a zip code needs to be done this way:
`WHERE zip LIKE '114%`, not with FULLTEXT.

MyISAM's FULLTEXT defaults to a minimum word size of 4 (that can be changed, but requires rebuilding the index).  InnoDB's FULLTEXT will find nothing it you feed it a word that is shorter than its min size (default is 3).  So, filter out short words.

Do not use leading "*" in the AGAINST, that does not work.  Even tacking a trailing "*" has troubles in your example -- note that '*point pleasant*' means "Look for words ending in 'point' and words starting with 'pleasant'.  Again, you need to massage the incoming query.

Suggest you parse the incoming query, make intelligent guesses of what the user is asking for (Examples:  114, by itself, is a 3-digit zip; 114 plus something else could be an address).  Learn about "regular expressions", you will need them.

Comment: Please view my `SHOW CREATE TABLE tbl_property;` [http://justpaste.it/jsfs](http://justpaste.it/jsfs)

Comment: can you please provide me working query for my scenario as well?

Comment: Use TINYINT UNSIGNED instead of INT(2) (etc).  Use VARCHAR, not CHAR for any fields that are not fixed length.  Use DATE, TIME, DATETIME, etc, instead of VARCHAR for such fields.  Don't index fields that vary too little, such as number of baths.  Use compound indexes -- after analyzing the queries you get to see which fields are most commonly used.  A likely candidate (beds, price) because of `WHERE beds=3 AND price < 300000'.  Keep in mind that MySQL will (usually) use only one index in a SELECT.  All properties are integral number of acres?  Perhaps FLOAT.

Comment: Do you really have 2.7M active properties?  Or do you have a purging policy?  With MyISAM and lots of DELETEs, you should probably `OPTIMIZE TABLE` once a month.  Of what use is `st_num` and `st_sfx`, given that you have `addr`.  I'm sorry to digress in to this criticism, but if you will get some performance improvements by improving the schema.

Comment: I see one TEXT field and a large VARCHAR; move them to a separate table.  This will improve queries in two ways -- by not having as much bulk to step over, and by allowing implicit tmp tables (in complex SELECTs) to be MEMORY instead of MyISAM.

Comment: As for providing a "working query", my suggestions involved bunch of PHP code; I am not willing to provide that.  Please clean up what you can in the numerous suggestions I have given you, then come back (in a separate posting) for more assistance.

Comment: thank you very much dear Sir for you valuable information in this regard. Can you please tell me how can I optimize my table?

Comment: yes I do have 2.7M active properties in my system but now my client wants to use keword based search like [http://www.trulia.com](http://www.trulia.com) therefore I came up with this idea.

Comment: Why are you not willing to provide that? I have posted mine code cant we get it fix? thanks

Comment: I am not willing to provide the 300-2000 lines of code that you need for your project.  I tackled a project like this long ago.  It is not trivial.  And most of the code needs to be outside of SQL.

Comment: Just call me the supergeek of MySQL.  ;)